# Need to create javax.ws.rs.client.Client for each webservcie call

Tags: java, rest, java-ws

Create a javax.ws.rs-ap.jar client and send the request to the server:

```
   javax.ws.rs.client.Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().build();
```

I have writtten the above code to call multiple api(get user by id, get all users and deleteUser).

My question is here.

I am creating a new Client for each api cal.

Just wanted to know i can create a single instance of Client and make multiple calls ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a Client can be reused as long as it's lifecycle is managed properly. This means when a client instance is created, it should be closed properly as well using the `close()` method, once it's purpose is served. Refer to the [Client API documentation](https://jersey.java.net/apidocs-javax.jax-rs/2.0.1/javax/ws/rs/client/Client.html).

Note that multiple client instances would be needed if each client has a different client configuration.